# Javascript For Loop and Reduce. Is this correct

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm new to JavaScript so I've been trying to find ways to understand more of it. I've been creating codes in two ways. For loops and higher order function using array methods such reduce, map, filter, etc.
I'm going to post an array, a reduce code and for loops. Can anyone see if I'm doing the for loop correctly?

```
var people = [
{ name: "Jesse", age: 32, gender: "male" },
{   name: "Tommi", age: 40, gender: "female" },
{   name: "John",   age: 19, gender: "male" },
{   name: "Toni",   age: 50, gender: "trans" },
{   name: "Gene",   age: 19, gender: "trans" },
{   name: "Freddy", age: 80, gender: "male" }
```

];

I know this method is correct

```
var reduceGenderSum = people.reduce(function(obj, person){
if(!obj[person.gender]){
    obj[person.gender] = 1;
} else {
    obj[person.gender] += 1;
}
return obj;
}, {})
```

But I'm not too sure about this way using for loop, but can anyone double check for me.

```
function genderSumFn(){
var count = 0;
var count2 = 0;
var count3 = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < people.length; i ++){
    if(people[i].gender === 'male'){
        count ++;
    } else if(people[i].gender === 'female'){
        count2 ++
    } else {
        count3 ++
    }
}
return { male: count, female: count2, trans: count3 };
}
```

I get the same output. I just wanted to make sure I am doing it correctly using the for loop.

Comment: Your code works perfectly.

Comment: Yes, your code is correct.

Comment: thank you guys! i am so happy! i've been so comfortable with using the reduce that i started struggling converting it using for loops!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code is working and OP wanted us to check the code is working

Comment: both are not interchangable, because the for loop relies on fixed gender, whereas the reduce version works with an arbitrary count of genders.

Comment: nina is there a way i can create a for loop that i don't have to rely on using fixed gender? i was afraid that i was hard coding coding to get the same output as using the reduce method

Answer (score 0):

Fo a nearly same approach for the `for` loop as in the callback of the `reduce`, you could use an object as well.

```js
function getGenderCount(people) {
    var count = {},
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
        count[people[i].gender] = count[people[i].gender] || 0;
        count[people[i].gender]++;
    }
    return count;
}

var people = [{ name: "Jesse", age: 32, gender: "male" }, { name: "Tommi", age: 40, gender: "female" }, { name: "John", age: 19, gender: "male" }, { name: "Toni", age: 50, gender: "trans" }, { name: "Gene", age: 19, gender: "trans" }, { name: "Freddy", age: 80, gender: "male" }];

console.log(getGenderCount(people));
```